# Any solution for sharing text with friend but prevent copy?

Tags: applications

Is there any App / solution can suffice the follow needs ?

1. I want to share some text with friends (not public).
2. I don't want them be able to copy the text in anyway.
3. able view the text offline.
4. cross-platform. (not a must)

Answer (score 0):

Simple idea is to type the required message in any text editor on phone (or in any messaging app itself / or write a Gmail and save as draft) and then take a screenshot of the text and send it over to the intended people!

Comment: what if there is a lots of text, like a 
Business Proposal ? Also, make it into image and send to the other will make it way too easy to share out.